# Different result for same system with Simulink and tf()

Tags: matlab, controls, system, simulink

Take a look at the following simple system

[image]

where **Kp**=7130 and **Kd**=59.3880. These values are designed so that the system should exhibit an overshoot of 20% and steady-state error less than 0.01. The Simulink model yields correct results whereas `tf()` doesn't. This is the model

[image]

and its result is

[image]

Now implementing same system with `tf` as follows:

```
clear all
clc
kp=7130;
kd=59.3880;
num=[kd kp];
den=[1 18+kd 72+kp];
F=tf(num,den);
step(F)
stepinfo(F)
```

yields different overshoot.

[image]

Any suggestions why there is an inconsistent response? Do I have to put the system in specific form in order to use `tf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is considering correct the response of the Simulink implementation. `step` is giving you the correct response.

A **pure derivative** does not exists in Simulink, and if out try a transfer function block with `[kd, kp]` as numerator and `[1]` as denominator you will get an error.

**The derivative is a filter with a pole when you use the fixed step integrator**, the behavior with variable step [is quite uncertain, and should be avoided](https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98699-why-do-i-receive-incorrect-results-when-i-use-the-derivative-block-in-simulink). The closed loop system you get with your controller has relative degree one (1 zeros, 2 poles).

If you look at the response, the Simulink implementation starts with `dy/dt = 0` for `t = 0`, and this is not possible with this kind of closed loop system. The correct response is the one of `tf` (`dy/dt > 0` for `t = 0`).

Your closed loop transfer function is correct, and you should consider its response as correct. Try to simulate the transfer function in the image with Simulink. You will see the same response of the `step` command.

Let's test this with some code:

[image]

In the image we have three test:

- the analytic transfer function
- an approximation of the derivative
- the simulation with your derivative block

Try to implement it and test the value of `0.001` in the tf `s / (0.001 s + 1)`, you will see that if you decrease the coefficient towards 0, the response of *Transfer Fnc2* will approximate the one of the analytic closed loop tf (up to a point Simulink will not evaluate the derivative and will stop the simulation).
And finally, the analytic transfer function in Simulink gives the same response of the `step` command.

In the comment you said you evaluated the inverse laplace, so let us check also the inverse laplace. The symbolic toolbox will do that for us:

```
syms s kp kd t

Plant = 1/(s^2 + 18 * s + 72)
Reg = kp + kd * s

L = Plant * Reg
ClosedLoop = simplify(L / (1 + L))
Step = 1/s

ResponseStep = simplify(ilaplace(ClosedLoop * Step))

ResponseStep_f = matlabFunction(simplify( ...
  subs( ...
    subs(ResponseStep, kp, 7130), kd, 59.3880)));

t_ = linspace(0, 0.15, 200);
y_ = arrayfun(t_closedLoop_d, t_);
plot(t_, y_);
```

[image]

as you can see the inverse Laplace shows an overshoot of more than 25%.

EDIT: Evaluating the inverse Laplace that you evaluated at [this link](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B59.388s%2B7130%7D%7Bs%5Cleft(s%5E%7B2%7D%2B77.388s%2B7202%5Cright)%7D)

[image]

Again the overshoot is at 25.9%

Comment: Thanks for the answer. `tf` yields incorrect overshoot (i.e. 27%) but the design for kd and kp should yield an overshoot of 20%. I've double checked it via determining the inverse laplace transform.

Comment: Also, how do you think to implement a non-causal controller?

Comment: Yes I'm sure. Take a look at https://www.symbolab.com/solver/inverse-laplace-calculator/inverse%20laplace%20%5Cfrac%7B59.388s%2B7130%7D%7Bs%5Cleft(s%5E%7B2%7D%2B77.388s%2B7202%5Cright)%7D

Comment: The inverse laplace at the link you posted has the same overshoot!

Comment: Same overshoot of what? 27?

Comment: 25.9%, Image in the last part of the answer (that is exactly the same overshoot predicted by `step(tf([...`)

Comment: yes you are right. It seems there is an issue with the way kd is designed.

Comment: The structure of the controller should be entirely reconsidered. At the moment it is non-casual and it is improbable it will work outside a simulation environment.